# biblatex: \autocite(s) separate entries by a dot instead of semicolon

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm using the biblatex package with

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
```

and the command `\autocite{ref1,ref2}`
correctly produces footnotes with reference1; reference2.

However, I would like the two references to be separated by a dot like $\bullet$, instead of semicolon ;

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter between several citations is usually called `\multicitdelim`. You can redefine this macro as you see fit.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\enskip\textbullet\enskip}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P • Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.]